# Node.js, caman: Error: Image given has not completed loading only with jpg images

Tags: javascript, node.js, camanjs

Hy 
I'm editing various images that are stored locally on my pc, I have no problems with a png images, but when I try editing jpg images I always get the following error

```
this.context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.imageWidth(), this.image
                 ^
Error: Image given has not completed loading
```

here is my code

```
Caman('C://images//' + req.body['storedName'], function () {
    var regulations = JSON.parse(req.body['regulations']);
    this.saturation(regulations.saturation);
    this.sepia(regulations.sepia);
    this.vibrance(regulations.vibrance);
    this.sharpen(regulations.sharpen);
    this.brightness(regulations.brightness);
    this.contrast(regulations.contrast);
    this.exposure(regulations.exposure);
    this[req.body['preset']]();
    this.render(function () {
        this.save('C://images//' + req.body['storedName']);
    });
});
```

Any idea what the problem might be? Thanks.

**EDIT**
after @ lombausch comment I changed my code, so now it looks like this,

```
var myimage = new Canvas.Image();
myimage.onload = function() {
    Caman('C://images//' + req.body['storedName'], function () {
        var regulations = JSON.parse(req.body['regulations']);
        this.saturation(regulations.saturation);
        this.sepia(regulations.sepia);
        this.vibrance(regulations.vibrance);
        this.sharpen(regulations.sharpen);
        this.brightness(regulations.brightness);
        this.contrast(regulations.contrast);
        this.exposure(regulations.exposure);
        this[req.body['preset']]();
        this.render(function () {
            var extension = path.extname(req.body['storedName']);
            var filename = path.basename(req.body['storedName'],extension);
            this.save('C://images//' + filename + '-caman' + extension);
            res.json({ status:'success' });
        });
    });
};
myimage.onerror = function(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.json({status:"error", message:err});
};
myimage.src = 'C://images//' + req.body['storedName'];
```

the error doosn't show up anymore but nothing happens, and when I say nothing I mean nothing, not an error emssage, nor anything else,seems like the onload never get's fired.

Comment: how do you get the image on your pc?

Comment: Hope i got your question right:I just downloaded an image from google... can't see how this is can change something...

Comment: with nodejs http.request ?  or manually?

Comment: You need to show us the code you are doing to load your `this.image` as your error states that it is not done loading.

Comment: @lombausch: manually,

Comment: @lochemage: this is all my code, in the camanJS I read that: You can give Caman the path to an image on disk, and this is what I'm doing. If this is a wrong approach why would it work with png images?

Comment: I haven't used Caman yet, but could that be possible that those two operations (loading image and processing) are asynchronous? I suppose jpeg takes longer to decompress than png.

Comment: @lombausch, I changed my code just to be sure, I edited my question...

Comment: what about console output, or network traffic?

Comment: I just had a brief look into Caman docs - to me it seems like you need yo pass the img tag id into constructor not the path to source.

Comment: but I'm using caman on nodejs side, I have no image tag.

Comment: @lombausch I edited my code again adding an onerror handler, I get an [Error: error while reading from input stream] error only with jpg files, don't know if this is of any help.

Comment: It seems to be something involving the Operating system, I just tried running the same code on a linux machine and everything worked fine.